# Conditions on class parameters

Tags: python

I am creating a Class qubit which has 2 parameters: a and b. I want to make sure everytime user changes parameters, the condition a^2 +b^2=1 must hold . If the condition does not hold then it is an invalid input. 
A related Problem: Is there a way to run some function update() everytime the user changes parameters?

```py
class Qubit(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1
        self.b = 0
```

Comment: You can use properties instead of instance variable…

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE Can you specify how that would look like?

Comment: See @AKX answer

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing. Use `property`s so you get getter/setter behavior:

```py
class Qubit(object):
    def __init__(self, a=1, b=0):
        self._validate(a, b) 
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    @staticmethod
    def _validate(a, b):
        if a ** 2 + b ** 2 != 1:
             raise ValueError('{}^2 + {}^2 != 1'.format(a, b))

    # Getter for `a`
    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    # Setter for `a`
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._validate(a=value, b=self._b)
        self._a = value

    # (Repeat for `b`.)
```

Comment: This said, you might want to represent your `Qubit`s with a `namedtuple`, for instance, so they're immutable.

Comment: It would probably be better for the setters for `a` and `b` to modify *both* `_a` and `_b` to ensure the property, rather than raising an error (because otherwise, you can never change one without violating the property).

Comment: E.g., `def a(self, value): self._a = value; self._b = 1 - value**2`.

Comment: That's true. And at that point it'll be better to represent the Qubit as an immutable data structure such as a tuple.

Comment: (Heck, you could even use the built-in `complex` data type and just ensure `abs(q)` is always 1... :) )

Comment: Pretty sure you can modify the value with a single multiplication, too, since you are just rotating the point around the unit circle. (Actually, I guess it's no easier than just calculating `1 - other**2`.)

Comment: @AKX Thanks for the help! Though I can't represent Qubit as immutable data structure because I'm later gonna build quantum gates which will change the amplitudes of qubit.